# How to use "textures" with Flex charts?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm new to Flex...I'm wondering if I can make a flex bar chart display a "texture" instead of a color?

Answer (score 0):

http://vinothbabu.com/2010/04/13/flex-bar-chart-with-different-colors/

You need to write your own itemRenderer where you can specify the texture instead of colors.

Comment: You need to specify your texture in the itemRenderer, and it requires some sort of tweaking your code to fit texture there.

Comment: Anybody can tell me how itemrenderer works with flex stacked bar/column chart? any documents/code samples...etc